# Definition of smooth manifold using sheaves.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

While defining differential manifolds using the concept of sheaves [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Structure_sheaf) gives the following definition.

> A differentiable manifold (of class $C_k$) consists of a pair $(M, \mathcal{O}_M)$ where $M$ is a topological space, and $\mathcal{O}_M$ is a sheaf of local $\mathbb{R}$-algebras defined on $M$, such that the locally ringed space $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is locally isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{O})$. 
> [$\mathcal{O}(U)=C^k(U,\mathbb{R})$ is the structure sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^n$.]

In one of my courses I have been asked to verify whether the above definition is equivalent to the standard definition using atlases, but in that the condition of "locally" ringed spaces is missing, that is I am supposed to prove that $M$ is a smooth manifold if and only if there is a sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M$ of local $\mathbb{R}$-algebras defined on $M$, such that the **ringed space** $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is locally isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{O})$ where $\mathcal{O}(U)=C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb{R})$ is the structure sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So I was wondering if the condition of every stalk being a local ring (locally ringed space) is necessary in the case of smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Isomorphisms of locally ringed spaces are the same as isomorphisms of ringed spaces (which happen to be locally ringed), so you do not have to specify that $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is locally ringed.  That is, if $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is a ringed space which is locally isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{O})$, then the stalks of $\mathcal{O}_M$ are isomorphic to the corresponding stalks of $\mathcal{O}$, and thus are local rings.  The local isomorphisms from $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{O})$ are then automatically isomorphisms of locally ringed spaces (basically, because the condition for a morphism to be "local" involves only the ringed space structure, and so is satisfied by any isomorphism of ringed spaces).

So you can define a manifold as a ringed space that is locally isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{O})$.  However, it is better to define it as a locally ringed space because smooth maps between manifolds correspond to morphisms of locally ringed spaces, not morphisms of ringed spaces.  I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head (it seems rather complicated to construct one), but there isn't any reason to expect that a morphism of ringed spaces between two manifolds is the same thing as a smooth map.  The local condition on morphisms says that pullback respects evaluation of smooth functions at points: that is, if $\varphi:(M,\mathcal{O}_M)\to(N,\mathcal{O}_N)$ is a morphism, $f\in\mathcal{O}_N(U)$, and $p\in \varphi^{-1}(U)$, then $(\varphi^*f)(p)=f(\varphi(p))$.  In this way, the pullback map $\varphi^*$ on the sheaves is completely determined by the map of sets $M\to N$.  If you drop this condition (i.e., you talk only about morphisms of ringed spaces instead of morphisms of locally ringed spaces), it seems very difficult to control what the pullback map $\varphi^*$ can possibly look like.

So to sum up: you don't need to say "locally ringed" instead of "ringed" when talking about the *objects* of the category of manifolds, but you (probably) do need to say it when talking about the *morphisms* (though I don't know a counterexample that would prove this).